# Elixir Enum, filter and group

Tags: enums, elixir

what's the most elegant way in Elixir to transform

```
[["A","B","foo"],["A","B","bar"],["A","B","baz"],["C","D","foobar"],["C","D","bla"],["E","F","blabla"]]
```

into:

```
[["A","B","foo","bar","baz"],["C","D","foobar","bla"],["E","F","blabla"]]
```

Basically I want to iterate over the input list and group by the first two elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'd group by `Enum.take(2)` and then `flat_map` each group with `Enum.drop(2)`:

```
[["A","B","foo"],["A","B","bar"],["A","B","baz"],["C","D","foobar"],["C","D","bla"],["E","F","blabla"]]
|> Enum.group_by(&Enum.take(&1, 2))
|> Enum.map(fn {key, value} ->
  key ++ Enum.flat_map(value, &Enum.drop(&1, 2))
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[["A", "B", "foo", "bar", "baz"], ["C", "D", "foobar", "bla"],
 ["E", "F", "blabla"]]
```

Note that this will also work if any item in the input list has > 3 elements; in that case it'll just concat them:

```
[["A","B","foo","z","zz"],["A","B","bar"],["A","B","baz"],["C","D","foobar"],["C","D","bla"],["E","F","blabla"]]
```

will output:

```
[["A", "B", "foo", "z", "zz", "bar", "baz"], ["C", "D", "foobar", "bla"],
 ["E", "F", "blabla"]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactely what I want! Thank you!